# How to switch to a window (NOT TAB) in karate?

Tags: karate, new-window

I have PayPal payment method in my application and on click of the PayPal button, it opens in a new window to enter the credentials

I am not sure how to switch to that window in Karate. Can someone help me on this?
I assume `switchPage()` works only for switching a tab and not window

Please also let me know if there is any other way to switch to that PayPal window.

Comment: switchPage(0) works only for switching to a tab right? But my requirement is to switch to a window. Sorry if my understanding is wrong

Comment: I don't think you can, but you are welcome to try. the linked answers provide some suggestions. you will have to do some research